# Python Flask Session with Login

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

Is it possible to create Flask Sessions without Login Fields, For Example user can enter only Email address in User Name Field, which will create Session with certain expiration time, till  the session is active, User2 cannot create session with same name.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

At first flask by default do not store session on server - only safe cookies.

If you want use email as id (`user.get_id()` method) you can't. But you can create special cache (dict or etc) on server with active sessions and use unique keys as id and do not login users with exist email.